# Does the Interval Timer on the Z6 (or Z7) automatically disable after each sequence/series of shots?

Tags: nikon, intervalometer, nikon-z7, nikon-z6

I have the Canon RP and am disappointed to find that the Interval Timer disables itself after each sequence and must be re-enabled for every new sequence.  So, every press of the shutter requires going into the menu again.  I'm hoping the Z6 remains enabled until disabled by the photographer.  Better, I hope it might be able to remain enabled after powering the camera off and then on again.  Can anyone please advise on the Z6's function regarding the Interval Timer?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Z6/Z7 manual](https://www.zshooters.com/wp-content/manuals/nikon-z6-z7-reference-manual-en.pdf),

> Interval timer shooting will pause when Self-timer (E) is selected for release mode or if the camera is turned off and then on again (when the camera is off, batteries and memory cards can be replaced without ending interval timer photography). Pausing shooting does not affect interval timer settings.

And in order to continue after pausing,

> ❚❚ Resuming Interval Timer Photography
> To resume shooting immediately, select Restart.

So I'd say that the Z6 retains the interval settings after various interruptions (pause, power off/on) but you'd need to manually 'unpause' the interval timer after the interruption...

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. Nikon offers the option to reset the mode only for HDR but for all other modes, you have to unset it to return back to normal shooting.

Specifically for the interval timer, sometimes the option is grey out if you have incompatible mode selected like the Self-Timer. I did not try to select the Self-Timer while in Interval Timer mode but I would guess it wil stop the interval timer shooting instead of being greyed out.